# D7 views node references. Do not displays first node

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have 2 content types: Page and Paragraph.
Page has field node reference which made through view(outputs as checkboxes). View has contextual filter - Paragraph node author id (uid).
I create user, then create 2 nodes of type Paragraph.

Then I create node of type Page and in node reference field I see only one node of type Paragraph. I search for my Paragraph nodes in http://example.com/admin/content and open each paragraph in devel.

Both of Paragraph nodes are published. Both has user id in uid. But in the field I see only one of them.

Trying to figure out what's happening I call views_get_view_result with my view. And see only the second node.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of googling found how to deal with this issue. 
Thanks to this [Actual output in view is different than preview](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133657/actual-output-in-view-is-different-than-preview)

In view settings go to other section -> query settings -> Disable SQL Rewriting.

After saving the view I've seen all my nodes into the node reference field.